# How to force ActiveMQ client to set client id and subscription name

Tags: activemq-artemis

My MQ server is built with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0.

Recently I realized that some clients are connecting to my ActiveMQ Artemis without setting client id and subscription and subscribing to some topics. Their queues became UUID like below:

[image]

So, I want to know how to force ActiveMQ clients to set client id and subscription name? And if they don't config client id and subscription name, the ActiveMQ Artemis can kick them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't exactly *force* clients to set their client ID and subscription name, but you can change the security authorization configuration to prevent clients from creating non-durable subscriptions.

Non-durable subscribers create non-durable queues which use the UUID naming convention shown in your web-console screenshot. If you wish to prevent this then modify your `security-settings` in `broker.xml` and remove the `permission` whose `type` is `createNonDurableQueue`. Here's the default `security-settings`:

```xml
      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>
```

This is the permission I'm referring to:

```xml
<permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
```

If you remove that `permission` *or* remove the user's role from the `permission` then that user will no longer be able to create a non-durable queue on the matching address. However, as long as they have the `createDurableQueue` and `deleteDurableQueue` permissions they will be able to create & delete a durable subscription.

Comment: Thanks. Well, for some reasons, sometime the clients need to subscrtibe topic with non-durable way. Then, any suggestion for forcing non-durable clients to set client ids and displaying client ids on the queue names created by clients ?

Comment: Even if the consuming application set the JMS client ID and created a non-durable subscription the broker would still use a UUID for the queue's name. The only time the broker uses the client ID as part of the queue name is when the consuming application creates a durable subscription.